# How do you spawn a child process in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I want to offload a block of code in my main process to child process to make it run concurrently. I also want to have the PID of the spawned child process so I can monitor and kill it if necessary.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can use the `fork` kernel method. Here is an example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
puts "This is the master process."

child_pid = fork do
  puts "This is the child process"
  exit
end

puts "The PID of the child process is #{child_pid}"
```

The `fork` method returns the PID of the process it forks and executes any code in the block passed. Like regular Ruby blocks it keeps the bindings of the parent process.

It is a good idea to make your forked process `exit`.

Comment: One thing to remember with Ruby is that not all things work exactly the same way in Windows versus *nix. Sometimes they're completely unimplemented on Windows, so use at your own peril.

Comment: @Vadim I think that is a feature, not a bug.

Comment: I'm a bit confused about calling `exit` - why (or when) is it needed?

Comment: @skwisgaar `exit` is needed to ensure the forked process terminates. You may end up with zombie or orphan processes otherwise. More at: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20689837/3784008. Short explanation: call `exit` inside your forked process after it finishes running its code, or the new `ruby` process that was spawned will continue running in the background.

Comment: `exit` with default code is not necessary with this form of fork, as " block is run in the subprocess, and the subprocess terminates with a status of zero." To avoid creating a zombie you need to either `Process.wait` or `Process.detach` in the parent process. 

http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Kernel.html#method-i-fork

Comment: Is Kernel fork different from Process.fork? If so, how?

Answer (score 54):

In addition to Chris' great answer, remember to call `Process.wait` from your master in order to reap your child process, else you'll leave zombies behind.

Example as requested in comments:

```
pid = Process.fork do
  puts "child, pid #{Process.pid} sleeping..."
  sleep 5
  puts "child exiting"
end

puts "parent, pid #{Process.pid}, waiting on child pid #{pid}"
Process.wait
puts "parent exiting"
```

Comment: Sweet, that was an awesome tip.

Comment: Where and how would you place Process.wait in the accepted answer above?

Comment: Note that `Process.wait` without an argument waits for _any_ child, so in a more general case, this code snippet would exit the parent even if that specific child process above doesn't exit. A more exact version would say `Process.wait(pid)` instead.

Comment: Is there a platform-independent way to do this (i.e. without `fork`, since that's only on Unix)?

Comment: Let's agree in `Process.waitall`. The parent will wait until **ALL** childs exit.

Answer (score 7):

In 1.9 you can use Process.spawn command.
See also http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Running_Multiple_Processes

Answer (score 2):

If you are happy to use Threads, rather than Processes, then something like this *may* be a bit more scaleable to more-than-one fork:

```
def doit(x)
    sleep(rand(10))
    puts "Done... #{x}"
end

thingstodo = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g"]
tasklist = []

# Set the threads going

thingstodo.each { |thing|
    task = Thread.new(thing) { |this| doit(this) } 
    tasklist << task
} 

# Wait for the threads to finish

tasklist.each { |task|
    task.join
}
```

Please see John Topley's excellent comments and reference, below, regarding the Ruby execution model and its restrictions.

---

Just edited to correct a glaring error (no assignment to task), and to follow @(Jason King)'s advice.

Comment: Presumably these are Green Threads rather than proper OS threads?

Comment: Read this regarding Ruby 1.9: http://www.igvita.com/2008/11/13/concurrency-is-a-myth-in-ruby/

Comment: Should be: `Thread.new(thing) { |it| doit(it) }`

Because `thing` is reset on each iteration, so there's no guarantee that the right thread will get the right `thing`