# Ruby poor performance in thread

Tags: ruby

I have a function that does IO/computation. I made a demo function which copies ~300MB from here to there. If I run it in a thread which I immediately join, it is much slower than if I run it without a thread. I checked with:

```
def cp
  start = Time.now
  FileUtils.cp_r("C:/tmp", "C:/tmp1")
  fin = Time.now - start
  p fin
end
```

Comparing these:

```
cp

Thread.new{cp}.join
```

the first `cp` call is always two to four times faster than the threaded call. The same happens if I do

```
cp

Thread.new{cp}

sleep 200
```

I heard about GIL, etc., but here, only one thread runs at a time, so no race for running time. Any ideas on how I can make it faster or why that is happening?

Comment: I can not reproduce the speed difference. The version called from a separate thread takes roughly the same time as called from the main process. Linux x86_64, Ruby 1.9.3p429 . I'd also add file operations heavily depend on the underlaying operating system and its caching capabilities. The cache has to be cleared/invalidated between calls.

Comment: The OP is on Windows, that might be causing speed differences due to its threading. I haven't dug into that as I quit developing and running on Windows years ago, but I seem to remember it doesn't support threads like *nix systems.

Comment: Wait... are you benchmarking both the plain and with-thread version in the same run?  Those need to be separate runs, so that you can isolate the effects of file cache & etc.

Answer (score 1):

Threading isn't a guarantee that things will run faster, or even the same speed, as non-threaded code, at least currently with MRI. JRuby might be better. Your `cp` isn't getting the full attention of the CPU, which is why doing it without threading, and allowing it to block until done, is faster.

Consider using `fork` instead.

"[A dozen (or so) ways to start sub-processes in Ruby: Part 1](http://devver.wordpress.com/2009/06/30/a-dozen-or-so-ways-to-start-sub-processes-in-ruby-part-1/)" looks useful. Also "[How do you spawn a child process in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307070/how-do-you-spawn-a-child-process-in-ruby)".

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer, but 2 things arise then..:

When I did join on thread it was also as slow as before, how can that be explained?
How can I track the status of my 'forked' threads?

Comment: "How can I track the status of my 'forked' threads?"? Use `Process.wait`?

Comment: Sorry, what I meant is that it is impossible to have lets say some dictionary which is updated by threads as they go

Comment: No, it's not impossible to modify something by threads. That's what [`Queue`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/thread/rdoc/Queue.html) is for.

Comment: I talked about achieving this behavior using forked processes. It is impossible to change one critical object, thus it is not sufficient to us fork

Comment: Sigh. You said "updated by threads". That's not forked. It's important to use the right terms. Another method to consider is the "block" form of `Open3.popen3` and call a sub-script or the built-in `copy` or `cp` . You can write/read using stdin/stdout to that sub-shell. Be aware of the need to close the `stdin` talking to the sub-shell as that can help avoid hanging in some apps. Because you're on Windows there might be limitations to what's available to you.

Comment: Thanks, Tin Man :), Cant rep you just jet.